# Why does this RE not work and the group function failed?

Tags: python, regex

```
match_next = re.search(r'(再来週)の(.曜日)', '再来週の月曜日')
```

when I run match_next.group[1], I got the following:

```
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Even if the match fails, why does the group function report this error?

Comment: `group` is a function not an iterable

Comment: Group 1 is always 再来週 though. Are you sure you don't want the day of the week (group 2) instead?

Comment: I should have used '()' instead of '[]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) have the properties and how to use them. Basically the `group` method of the Match Object should be called with 1 or more integers indicating which groups you want to access.

```py
match_next = re.search(r'(再来週)の(.曜日)', '再来週の月曜日')
match_next.group(1)
```